# CRM Dynamics SQL Query

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, crm

I am trying to write query in crm dynamics.
need help.

All contacts(Contact Entity) for ABC products(product entity) who have opened a case(case entity) in the last 12 months , WHERE the accounts(actount entity) for these Contract(contract entity) are current on Active

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Show some efforts & share your attempted query by editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are on dynamics on-premise, you wont be able to query the sql directly. Also I think that the architecture of dynamics wont work like that.

What you want to use is FetchXML. You can either use advanced find in your environment, set the conditions in the graphical interface and then click the "Download FetchXML" button. You can also use FetchXML builder in XRMToolBox